# Localizing XCAssets images in a Swift Package

Tags: xcode, localization, swift-package-manager

I'm using Swift Package Manager to create various libraries.
So far, I have localized `String`, so I added a Resources folder, some .lproj data and a defaultLocalization in my Package.swift file.

Now I'd like to localize some images in the XCAsset catalog, but when I click on "localize" on my image, the only localization that is proposed is the defaultLocalization from my Package.swift file (if I change "en" to "fr", I now get a "French" localize option, but English has gone).

How can I make Xcode aware of the supported localization inside my package ?

Comment: One answer was posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620892/10408494