# How to localize image in SwiftUI in SPM package?

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization

I've dealt with localization for texts, but I'm having problems with images' localization. My package structure looks like this, on the screen below:
[SPM package structure and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crorg.png)

The screenshot clearly shows how the instance of the `Text` class worked well, but there are problems with the `Image`

My code for this:

```swift
VStack {
  Image("flag", bundle: .module)
  Text("greetings", bundle: .module)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xcode Version 15.0 beta 2**

It is a bit tricky as it is not as straightforward as it would be on a Xcode project, and it seems to be a bug.

To add localized images on a Swift Package, follow the below steps.
*Lets say we want to have images in English and French.*

1. Add English as the `defaultLocalization` in your `Package.swift` file.

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "MyDesignPackage",
  defaultLocalization: "en",

// More Setup
)
```

2. Add only one `Images.xcassets` file under the `Resources` folder.

[image]

3. Create a `New Image Set` in the `Images.xcassets` file (name it `flag` like your example), and click on the `Localization` button on the right panel.

[image]

4. Select the English language.

From there, only `English` is shown, as it is the one declared as the `defaultLanguage`. Next steps will Add the French language.

5. Go back to the `Package.swift` file, and change the default language to French.

```swift
defaultLocalization: "fr"
```

*Package will load when doing this... You might need to build the project (⌘+B) to load the French language.*

6. Go back to your image on your ``Images.xcassets` file, and the French language will be available to be clicked on the right panel.

[image]

7. Select the French language and add the desired images. Put the `defaultLocalization` back to English, as the `Any Appearance` section of the image will select this language.

You will then be able to setup the image the way it should on a Swift Package.

```swift
// Access the image
let localizedFlag = Image("flag", bundle: .module)

// iOS 17
let localizedFlag = Image(.flag, bundle: .module)
```